# Google Script - function comparing if date is older than today

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-comparison

there are dates in one column, which is automatically updated in case of changing status of some other column. In case of changed from "Open" to "In progress" it sets today`s date.

I need a function which is automatically doing "something" in case that the date is older than today.

So far have this code, but it doesnt work and I don`t know why.
Thanks

```
function backgroundformate() {
  var odpovediSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Odpovědi formuláře");
  var lastRow = odpovediSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnH = odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);

  for (var i=1; i < columnH.length; i++) {
    var dataday = parseInt(new Date(columnH[i][8]).getTime()/day);
    if (dataday < today) {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("red")}
    else {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("yellow")}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to parse dates to compare them, JavaScript can do that natively.
here is your working code :

```
function backgroundformate() {
  var odpovediSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Odpovědi formuláře");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = odpovediSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnH = odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,0,0));// I set the hour to near midnight so you can get the right result today until 23:59:59 

  for (var i=1; i < columnH.length; i++) {
    var dataday =columnH[i][0];
    if (dataday < today) {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("red")}
    else {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("yellow")}
  }
}
```

Also, you did make a mistake in this code :

```
var dataday = parseInt(new Date(columnH[i][8]).getTime()/day);
```

the value you are looking for is at index 0 since you only get data from this column when you defined the range.
The code should have been been

```
var dataday = parseInt(new Date(columnH[i][0]).getTime()/day);
```

but anyway, the parsing is not necessary.

That said, is is not good practice to call ss service in a loop, you could do that much more efficiently using arrays and single SS calls.
Code goes like this, please try and compare execution speeds.

```
  function backgroundformate() {
      var odpovediSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Odpovědi formuláře");
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
      var columnH = odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
      var columnHBG = odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getBackgrounds();
      var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,0,0));

      for (var i=0; i < columnH.length; i++) {
        var dataday =columnH[i][0];
        if (dataday < today) {
          columnHBG[i][0]='#F00';
        }else{
          columnHBG[i][0]='#FF0';
        }
      }
      odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setBackgrounds(columnHBG);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will only work when prompted by the user at this point.

You have two choices, either put a trigger on it that lets the script run for example every 5 minutes, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Or start the function as an onEdit(e) that automatically triggers the script when anything in the sheet is changed. However, this might slow down working in the sheet, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

I am not sure if you are saying your script is not working as it should or it is not being triggered. If you want me to look at your script please put a link to the google sheet.

```
function backgroundformate() {
  var odpovediSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Odpovědi formuláře");
  var lastRow = odpovediSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnH = odpovediSheet.getRange(2, 8, odpovediSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);

  for (var i=1; i < columnH.length; i++) {
    var value = columnH[i][8].getValue();
    var dataday = parseInt(value/day);
    if (dataday < today) {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("red")}
    else {odpovediSheet.getRange(i+1, 8, lastRow, 1).setBackground("yellow")}
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. I count with the fact that I need to set a trigger. I have a problem with the function itself. The script is not working.

Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_WvTQcinr6ir2jxjjwVKYMlV9_tWZcVyZR0zsGBTxow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have edit access so cannot see your script. I think that the dates in your script are not from the same format as in your sheet. Put a logger behind var today ( Logger.log(today) ) and behind var dataday ( Logger.log(dataday) ) and compare the two logs.

Comment: Try adding those logs and tell me if there is any difference.

Comment: [17-08-01 17:08:53:195 CEST] 17378.0
[17-08-01 17:08:53:196 CEST] NaN
[17-08-01 17:08:53:199 CEST] NaN
[17-08-01 17:08:53:201 CEST] NaN

Today is 17378.0
dataday NaN
,so bad formate?

Comment: Yes you cannot define a Date like you have done in the Variable Dataday. The value you are getting is already a Date. Just parseInt the specific column and divide that by your day variable. If you are not certain that the date in the column H is formatted properly you can first format the column before starting the loop by using Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"). However, as you are using the parse that will not be necessary I assume.

Comment: See  above added script that will help you further I hope.

Comment: I tried it again. Nothing new. New code in the next answer.